# kml not loading on ec2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am having similar problem like this post refers to: 
[KML layer problems in Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317090/kml-layer-problems-in-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

My kml file is not loading when hosted on my ec2 instance.
Its working when it is hosted for example on my google drive.
My ec2 port 80 is open for all and I do not block anything with iptables.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var src = "http://{my host}/locations/test.kml";
       var map;

      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });        
        loadKmlLayer(src, map);
      }
      function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          preserveViewport: false,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What is the [status](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus)? What is the URL of the KML?  Is your server set up to serve KML?

Comment: Status of what? My server is a simple webserver, that has the kml file publicly available. e.g. If you put my url in a browser, the file would download normally

Comment: Follow the link ([KmlLayerStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus) of the KmlLayer).

Comment: Where can I see this? In the code? In the browser (chrome developer tools)

Comment: [Example page that displays the KmlStatus of the KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml//hkisland.kml) or see [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561979/issues-with-kml-link-to-google-maps-api/24562397#24562397)

Comment: The status is: FETCH_ERROR

Comment: What do you mean by: set up to serve kml?

Comment: FETCH_ERROR means: "The document could not be fetched.", can't help with that without its public URL. [FAQ: KML MIME types](https://developers.google.com/kml/faq#mimetypes).  See also: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server

Comment: i tried adding the mime types and still didn't work. So I've tried something more basic and checked if google is even trying to access my server (tcpdump sniffing my eth0). And I was surprised to see no traffic. When I access the url directly (for example via web browser) I can see the http traffic. Why google doesn't even reach the server?

Comment: What is the URL you are using? What does a web sniffer tell you if you try to access it?

Comment: The url is http://my amazon ec2 public IP address/locations/test.kml. The sniffer doesn't show any traffic

Comment: I would rather not to post my ip here. You may send me messages to swiminter@gmail.com and I'll send it to you

Comment: Any further advice?

Comment: Try renaming it to .xml and see if it works then.

Comment: It worked!!!!! :) can you explain why?

Comment: Your server isn't configured to serve KML, servers are typically configured  to serve XML. See the links in my comment about KML MIME types.

Comment: But I did add the mime as mentioned in your links (I checked with a sniffer and saw the "content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" as it should be. Very strange....anyway, thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was finally resolved with changing the file extension from .kml to .xml as @geocodezip suggested